# how to get specific elements in tensor (pytorch)

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor, like:
input:

```
a = torch.rand(2,3,5)
```

output:

```
tensor([[[0.2764, 0.2209, 0.8007, 0.1246, 0.4302],
     [0.9716, 0.8063, 0.3904, 0.7574, 0.2392],
     [0.3366, 0.4209, 0.0527, 0.1328, 0.0441]],

    [[0.8166, 0.6519, 0.5450, 0.3072, 0.2716],
     [0.0583, 0.0613, 0.8984, 0.0110, 0.4744],
     [0.2269, 0.2693, 0.6447, 0.6078, 0.6148]]])
```

how can I get :

```
tensor([[[0.2764, 0.2209, 0.8007, 0.1246, 0.4302],
 [0.9716, 0.8063, 0.3904, 0.7574, 0.2392]],

[[0.8166, 0.6519, 0.5450, 0.3072, 0.2716],
 [0.2269, 0.2693, 0.6447, 0.6078, 0.6148]]])
```

---

I have tried gather(), but it does not work.

Comment: Can you clarify the expected shape of the output? Why did you think `gather()` was the function you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

try this .This should work

```
a[:,:-1, :]
```